Java mail sender with TLS fails with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed
I have the following code for sending an email from Java:
public class MailTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        
        String smtpHost="smtp.office365.com";
        String smtpPort ="587";
        String userName = "username";
        String userPassword = "password";
        String smtpProtocol = "smtp";
     
        String to = "user_to@domain.com"; 
        String from="user_from@domain.com";
        String smtpFrom=from;
        
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", smtpProtocol);
         
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.from", smtpFrom);
            
        Authenticator auth = null;
        
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
        props.put("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
        
        auth=new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,userPassword);
                }
        };
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
      
        session.setDebug(true);
        
        StringBuilder textSB=new StringBuilder();
        textSB.append("Test email");
        textSB.append("Host: "+smtpHost).append("\n");
        textSB.append("Protocol: "+smtpProtocol).append("\n");
        textSB.append("Port: "+smtpPort).append("\n");
        textSB.append("UserName: "+userName).append("\n");
     
        MimeBodyPart mbText = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbText.setContent(textSB.toString(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbText);
        
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        
        InternetAddress replyToAddress=new InternetAddress(replyTo);
        msg.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[] {replyToAddress});
        
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        
        InternetAddress [] addressTO= new InternetAddress[] {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTO);
        
        String subject="Email subject";
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        
        msg.setContent(mp);  
        Transport.send(msg);
        
    }        
}

I'm using javax.mail-1.5.5.jar
When running standalone in a jre1.8 (jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.412.b08-1.el7_9.tuxcare.els1.x86_64) on a Red Hat Linux it's OK, this is the trace:
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
smtpHost: smtp.office365.com
smtpPort: 587
userName: username
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 VI1PR07CA0277.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 14 Aug 2024 19:15:00 +0000 [08DCBBD8B6FCC66A]
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587

EHLO client_host_name
250-host.outlook.office365.com Hello [ip]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
   

STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.158 EEST|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.349 EEST|SSLCipher.java:1817|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.350 EEST|SSLCipher.java:1971|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.414 EEST|SSLCipher.java:1817|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.414 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.415 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.416 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.416 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.416 EEST|X509Authentication.java:215|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2024-08-14 23:34:00.417 EEST|SSLCipher.java:1971|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO client_host_name
250-host.outlook.office365.com Hello [ip]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<user_from@domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<user_to@domain.com>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   user_to@domain.com
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2024 22:15:01 +0300 (EEST)
From: user_from@domain.com
To: user_to@domain.com
Message-ID: <2121055098.1.1723662901773@client_host_name>
Subject: Email subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_1528902577.1723662901702"

------=_Part_0_1528902577.1723662901702
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test email
Host: smtp.office365.com
Protocol: smtp
Port: 587
UserName: user

------=_Part_0_1528902577.1723662901702--
.
250 2.0.0 OK <2121055098.1.1723662901773@host_name> [Hostname=host_name]
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT

But if I run in a Tomcat 8.5 server (with a cPanel involved), in a web application I get the error
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

This is the trace
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
smtpHost: smtp.office365.com
smtpPort: 587
userName: username
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false
220-client_host ESMTP Exim 4.96.2 #2 Wed, 14 Aug 2024 22:39:14 +0300
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587

EHLO client_host_name
250-client_host_name Hello some_host [ip]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPECONNECT
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPECONNECT", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 TLS go ahead
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2046)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:711)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at ro.fiveplus.cms.actions.ecomm.WebChatBotAction.mailTest(WebChatBotAction.java:265)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethodInsideSandbox(OgnlRuntime.java:1226)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1211)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1920)
        at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1996)
        at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
        at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:537)
        at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:501)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:492)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:544)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:490)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:438)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:250)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:179)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:142)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:89)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:203)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at ro.fiveplus.cms.filters.RefererFilter.doFilter(RefererFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:181)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:535)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1690)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The command for JVM reveals only one JVM
root@host [~]#  update-alternatives --config java

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.412.b08-1.el7_9.tuxcare.els1.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

The question is why is different behaivior and not working in second case?
I noticed also a different debug in second case that is not present in first one:
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"

And extension "AUTH" has different arg in first case
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN XOAUTH2"

in second case
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"

I don't know if it has a relevance, but shouldn't it be the same?

Different or same JVM in each case?

only a single jvm I found on the machine, using commandroot@host [~]#  update-alternatives --config java
There is 1 program that provides 'java'.
Selection    Command
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.412.b08-1.el7_9.tuxcare.els1.x86_64/jre/bin/java)

Nonetheless, it seems as if a different trust is being used. Try debugging ssl. From memory, you need -Djavax.net.debug=SSL. Give that a try and compare

I have edited my question, only in first case I get supplimentary log, I guess because in second case ssl/tls connection could not be set

It sounds like there is a certificate you need to add to your keystore.

but why is not needed in the first case? It's not the same trust store?

it depends on how your tomcat is configured, it might be set to use a different specified trust store. You will need to check the start parameters of the tomcat -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore or the tomcat config files server.xml or catalina.properties I would suggest also adding the handshake to the debug and testing it again: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake

You're using a relatively old version of JavaMail/JakartaMail. The latest using the javax.mail namespace is JakartaMail 1.6.7, the latest using the jakarta.mail namespace is Angus Mail 2.0.3.

In any case, are you sure that the second case doesn't have some sort of SMTP proxy to intercept the call? I find it rather suspect that it presents itself as "client_host ESMTP Exim 4.96.2" (the first trace, it presents itself as "Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service", which AFAIK, all Office 365 SMTP servers do). In other words, are you sure your hoster isn't trying to redirect the SMTP connection to its own SMTP server?

Well spotted @MarkRotteveel ;) Highly  unlikely that Microsoft would ever use Exim in any way. The general configuration involving both would be to use Exim as a 'smarthost' relaying to Microsoft. I have no explanation why ostensibly identical SMTP target addresses would bring in a smarthost

What is Exim, and how can I trace this, can you ellaborate? Thank you!

sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep 'exim' and see HERE

nothing as a response for sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep 'exim'

OK so Exim is definitely not installed on that box. Are you 100% sure you are running both versions of that mail code on the same box?

yes, the both versions are running on a same virtual machine, first with java -jar .... and second from tomcat web application (tomcat) where is a cpanel involved

It's not inconceivable that in the 'Tomcat case' the actual (non-virtual) host smtp is being used. An MTA is not installed in the vm

how do you suggest to further investigate?

I'm thinking. There are a lot of moving parts here. I've slightly altered the topic tags, which might help.

Given cPanel seems to include Exim (based on a glance in their documentation), I would hazard a guess that it is interfering here.

i deleted the answer but I think it's relevant both logs as a comparison

You may want to see to which IP address smtp.office365.com resolves from within your application. I'd hazard a guess that in your Tomcat situation, it resolves to 127.0.0.1 or some other local IP address instead of one of the Microsoft-owned IP addresses.

yes, it seems that exim it's enabled in whm/cpanel. I disalbed it with command service exim stop but now I have another error com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)

You didn't report on what happened when you followed Mark's last advice

ping smtp.office365.com would be a start or host smtp.office365.com

ping resolves with 40.101.69.2

for host: smtp.office365.com is an alias for outlook.office365.com.
outlook.office365.com is an alias for ooc-g2.tm-4.office.com.
ooc-g2.tm-4.office.com is an alias for outlook.ms-acdc.office.com.
outlook.ms-acdc.office.com is an alias for VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com.

next: VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has address 52.97.174.2
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has address 40.101.69.210
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has address 52.97.160.2
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has address 52.97.128.178
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has IPv6 address 2603:1026:301:2::2
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has IPv6 address 2603:1026:301:56::2
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has IPv6 address 2603:1026:301:15::2
VIE-efz.ms-acdc.office.com has IPv6 address 2603:1026:301:55::2

That's looking more promising, so you should try the Tomcat version under debug and see what happens

Difficult to put Tomcat under debug mode because it's in live mode but I'll keep it in mind as a last solution to investigate. I will get back with Tomcat installation information. Any other suggestion to investigate? Why if Exim service it's stopped the error is "Connection refused" without any detailed information, what could be the cause?

It's not inconceivable that your hosting provider doesn't want you connecting to any arbitrary smtp server, although that doesn't really tally with the fact that you can apparently do so successfully from a command line Java app. It might be worthwhile if you tell us what your entry point to mailing is when inside Tomcat

it's not about hosting provider that doesn't want to connect to any smtp server, I think there is a default setting in whm/cpanel/tomcat or elsewhere that I hope to find it with your help. I will get back with more information from the provider. About "entry point to mailing when inside Tomcat" how can I find this?

Well presumably you wrote the code that sends the mail in Tomcat?

yes, that's correct

Well it won't hurt to describe how that's activated

it't inside a web application based on a struts2 action that points finally to a jsp, so the code it's triggered by an url

I found the answer, it is a setting in WHM to allow user to send remote SMTP. In WHM under Plugins->ConfigServer Security & Firewall->Firewall Configuration, then in SMTP_ALLOWUSER field the cPanel user must be entered.

Right. I wonder why it was partly working then?

No, it wasn't working even partially, in Tomcat context

I'm talking about the non-Tomcat context

In non-Tomcat context I was under root user from Putty, this is the reason
